# Require.js, how can i exclude non .js file?

Tags: requirejs, r.js

i want to exclude `.coffee` file in the `app` directory i am building with `r.js`.

So this statement in `build.js`(build.js is in the **app** dir) produces ERROR :

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "../build/result.js",
    stubModules: ['cs', 'text'],
    exclude: ['coffee-script', 'myfile'], # ERROR, no such file myfile.js in app dir..
    optimize: "none",
    paths: {...}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may get what you want by using `fileExclusionRegExp: /\.coffee$/`